# Numpy bincount() with floats

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get a bincount of a numpy array which is of the float type:

```
w = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5])
print np.bincount(w)
```

How can you use bincount() with float values and not int?

Comment: What would you expect as a result from this kind of "strange" operation?

Comment: I want to know the number of occurences of each value. So the result would be : [2,1,1,1] As 0.1 occurs twice and the others once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want something like this?

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> w = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5])
>>> c = Counter(w)

Counter({0.10000000000000001: 2, 0.5: 1, 0.29999999999999999: 1, 0.20000000000000001: 1})
```

or, more nicely output:

```
Counter({0.1: 2, 0.5: 1, 0.3: 1, 0.2: 1})
```

You can then sort it and get your values:

```
>>> np.array([v for k,v in sorted(c.iteritems())])

array([2, 1, 1, 1])
```

The output of `bincount` wouldn't make sense with floats:

```
>>> np.bincount([10,11])
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

as there is no defined sequence of floats.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use `numpy.unique` before you use `bincount`. Otherwise it's ambiguous what you're counting. `unique` should be much faster than Counter for numpy arrays.

```
>>> w = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5])
>>> uniqw, inverse = np.unique(w, return_inverse=True)
>>> uniqw
array([ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.5])
>>> np.bincount(inverse)
array([2, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 11):

Since version 1.9.0, you can use `np.unique` directly:

```
w = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5])
values, counts = np.unique(w, return_counts=True)
```