# Spectra entropy is greater than 1

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, entropy

I am trying to calculate the spectral entropy of an array as follows:

```
array([0.00000000e+00, 1.00743814e-04, 2.01487627e-04, 2.20497985e+01,
       2.20498993e+01, 2.20500000e+01])
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450192/fastest-way-to-compute-entropy-in-python), I derived my code. however, I found my data was float and so I also adapted code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10125434/9473186) to formulate the following:

```
>>> def ent(data):
...     uniqw, inverse = np.unique(data, return_inverse=True)
...     p_data= np.bincount(inverse)/len(data) # calculates the probabilities
...     ent=entropy(p_data)  # input probabilities to get the entropy
...     return ent
```

The result is

```
>>> ent(freqArray)
1.791759469228055
```

How do I make my entropy lie between 0 and 1

Comment: Why do you think the entropy should be no greater than 1?  Entropy has units.

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but the data I am trying to classify has entropies between 0 and 1. I am working on audio frequencies

Comment: You could normalize to the maximum entropy (uniform input).  But are your inputs _samples_ or _probabilities_?

Comment: They are samples not probabilities

Comment: Should I divide them by their sum?

Comment: Just defining the entropy of “real number” (`float`) samples is hard, because you can’t easily approximate the probability distribution like you can with discrete quantities.  Are you sure that’s what you want to do?

Comment: If they are samples, rescaling won’t do anything (disregarding rounding).  If they’re probabilities, of course they should be normalized.  But the normalization I meant was on the entropy itself, not the data at all.