# Find most frequent value in an np.array gives back "TypeError: cannot cast array data from dtype('float64) to dtype('int64') according to safe rule"

Tags: python, numpy

In my project I'm creating an np.array like this:

```
values_array = np.array(0.00, dtype=np.float32)
```

After that I append more value in it during a while loop:

```
values_array = np.append(values_array, round(value, 2))
```

And this is how my final array's output looks like:

```
[0. 0.41 0.41 0.42 0.41 0.43]
```

But when I try to find the most frequent value in the array like this:

```
top_value = np.argmax(np.bincount(values_array))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot cast array data from dtype('float64) to dtype('int64') according to safe rule
```

How can I avoid it?

Comment: `bincount` wants integers, you have floats

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy bincount() with floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119441/numpy-bincount-with-floats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called `mode` [doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)). You can do this in different ways, one using the module `scipy` and the other using `statistics`.

```
from scipy import stats as st
st.mode(values_array)
```

or

```
import statistics as st
print(st.mode(values_array))
```